# How to filter the row data in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I want to filter the entire row data for ag-grid in an angular project. Is there any way?

```
<ag-grid-angular 
  [gridOptions]="iterationGridOptions" 
  columnDefs]="iterationGridDef" 
  [rowData]="gridincidentData" 
  rowHeight="36" 
  [editType]="'fullRow'" 
  [components]="components" 
  singleClickEdit="true" 
  (rowClicked)="onSprintRowClicked($event)" 
  (rowValueChanged)="onSprintRowValueChanged($event)">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

I want to write a filter for `gridincidentData`. I want only `isEnabled: true` values

here is my grid incident data looks like

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5ba8b60a7eae422533eb7e6b"),
  "_class": "com.agile.historicaldata.dao.ASM",
  "id": 65,
  "projectId": 1,
  "incidentData": [{
        "_id": "1",
        "openedBy": "DELA CRUZ, ANNABELLE",
        "isEnabled": false
      },

      {
        "_id": "1",
        "openedBy": "APACIBLE, LORELIE T",
        "isEnabled": true
      },
      {
        "_id": "4",
        "openedBy": "MASACLAO, JOMER R",
        "isEnabled": false
      },
      {
        "_id": "3",
        "openedBy": "MASACLAO, JOMER R",
        "isEnabled": true
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = {
  "_id": "5ba8b60a7eae422533eb7e6b",
  "_class": "com.agile.historicaldata.dao.ASM",
  "id": 65,
  "projectId": 1,
  "incidentData": [{
        "_id": "1",
        "openedBy": "DELA CRUZ, ANNABELLE",
        "isEnabled": false
      },

      {
        "_id": "1",
        "openedBy": "APACIBLE, LORELIE T",
        "isEnabled": true
      },
      {
        "_id": "4",
        "openedBy": "MASACLAO, JOMER R",
        "isEnabled": false
      },
      {
        "_id": "3",
        "openedBy": "MASACLAO, JOMER R",
        "isEnabled": true
      }]
      }
 let clonedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
 clonedData.incidentData = clonedData.incidentData.filter(({isEnabled})=> isEnabled)
 
 console.log("After Filtering Data is Same",data);
 console.log("After Filtering cloned Data changed",clonedData);
```

Comment: Is there any other way to write filter bcz I'm using gridincidentdata in multiple places like custom-filter

Comment: for that we need to clone the gridincidentData and we can apply the changes on the clonedGridincidentData. So the original gridincidentData won't change.